# Reboot a Server from Command Line?

Tags: command-line, server, reboot

How do I reboot a Ubuntu Server from the command line? `sudo reboot now` never seems to work for me. Because its a server, I don't have a window manager installed, so I can't do it from a GUI (which always seems to work).

[image]

I've had the problem for years on different versions of the operating system. It happens in virtual machines and on real metal. The same problem exists with `sudo shutdown now`, too.

I've lived with it in the past. The difference now is I don't want to just hit the power button because I might lose data.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown -r now` ?

Comment: `sudo reboot now` is not a valid option. see [man 8 reboot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/reboot.8.html)

Comment: Thanks  souravc - that's interesting. The command never complains about an invalid option. I'll test some of these when I get out of mysql.

Comment: `sudo init 6` must always work. Also, there are Ctrl+Alt+Del and REISUB.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Try using the following command to safely **reboot**:

```
sudo reboot
```

If, instead, you want to **shut down** the server safely, use this command:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: You did not mention "safely" in the `sudo reboot` method, it may mislead some users.

Comment: @rap-2-h Wait, so do you mean `sudo reboot` is safe or not safe?

Comment: @wisbucky : sudo reboot is safe

Comment: had a debate with a coworker about this today. Is this method preferred over `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205464/whats-the-difference-between-poweroff-and-halt

Answer (score 27):

For reboot, type the following

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `sudo shutdown -r now`, this command also effects an **immediate shut-down**:

```
sudo shutdown -h +0
```

Add the `-r` command to reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r -h +0
```

---

Output (running as root):

```
root@mydevwkstn:~# shutdown -r -h +0

Broadcast message from cjbs@mydevwkstn
        (/dev/pts/10) at 14:41 ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
root@mydevwkstn:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

### An alternate way:

```
sudo init 6
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Without the `init` program there could be no command interpreter process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reboot your system, using @Jay's solution, you'll notice that the reboot will be scheduled by one minute. If, instead, you want your system to reboot immediately, you can use the following command:

```
reboot -f
```

The `-f` parameter will force your reboot to happen as soon as you enter the command.