# Ubuntu 20.04 4K resolution low FPS / stuttering?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have setup Ubuntu 20.04 in Dual boot with Windows 10.

On Windows 10 @ 3840 x 2160 (16:9) resolution I do not have any issues with video, smooth scrolling, IDE, games.

However on Ubuntu @ 3840 x 2160 (16:9) resolution, I get stuttering low FPS for video, jaggy/rough scrolling.

When I set it to 2048 x 1152 (16:9) resolution it is way smoother and no issues.

My hardware info is the following:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4690K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Palit GeForce RTX 2070 8Gb
16Gb DDR3 2400mhz Corsair Vengeance RAM
LG 27inch 4K Monitor
```

These are the following things I've tried:

- Swapped HDMI to Displayport from GPU to Monitor
- Tried the prorietary Nvidia drivers (**version 440**), X.org drivers
- Restarting Gnome
- Updating the latest drivers and patches from Ubuntu

I am happy to use the monitor at a lower resolution but I am curious as to what the bottleneck is here?

Is there any fixes?

Comment: You can try this driver `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && apt update` then `sudo apt install  nvidia-graphics-drivers-440` it is a bit more up to date. The Nvidia drivers are not great on Ubuntu.

Comment: I believe ubuntu/gnome/nvidia is just weak in graphics performance compared to Windows. I use ubuntu for 16 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling fractional displaying on displays.
Go to Ubuntu settings / Displays, and set 100% for scale, and disable the "Fractionl Scaling" feature:

[image: Ubuntu settings]

Source: [Chrome menus too slow after enabling fractional scaling in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274719/chrome-menus-too-slow-after-enabling-fractional-scaling-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I'm using 100% with no franctional scaling, feels like 10Hz. reboot to Windows-10 feels like 60Hz

Answer (score 0):

Use a newer beta driver for Nvidia. 465 works.

Comment: I'm using 515, feels like 10Hz.  reboot to Windows-10 feels like 60Hz

Answer (score -1):

Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instead. There seems to be some incompatibility issues with nvidia drivers and the latest version of Ubuntu. See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276650/300358) to a similar question.