# Chrome menus too slow after enabling fractional scaling in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, google-chrome, scaling

A few weeks ago I set up fractional scaling to 125% in Ubuntu 20.04.

After that I noticed that some of the menus in chrome are **too** slow. When I disable fractional scaling the speed goes back to normal.

I tried to search but so far couldn't find anyone with the same problem, nor any other application that has the same issue (firefox works fine).

My computer is an X1 carbon 8th gen, with Intel UHD Graphics.

[image]

See video:

[image]

Comment: I'm running into the same issues: Firefox and enabled Hardware Acceleration on Ubuntu 20.10 leads into performance problems IFF I enable fractional scaling in Ubuntu.

Did anyone find a bug-report somewhere on Ubuntus or Firefox side?

Comment: Thank you. I realize the dropping frames on Chrome comes from this issue. Maybe is a bug on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 12):

I meet the same problem. One possible solution for me is to disable the hardware acceleration of Chrome:

1. Toggle **off**: Settings -> System -> "Use hardware acceleration when available"
2. Relaunch Chrome.

Tested and works on Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111.

Comment: Hey jalawov! Please make sure that your answer is detailed. You can add the steps regarding how to disable the hardware acceleration of Chrome. You can use the [edit] feature to edit your answer. Your contribution will be helpful to the community.

Comment: I've been searching for an answer for my slow chrome menus for months now, thank you so much!!! I never tied it to fractional scaling because I've had that on since installing Ubuntu. Turning off hardware acceleration solved the problem completely.

Comment: Also works for Brave browser (built on Chrome).

Comment: Dont be confused, this is Chrome settings, not the ones from Ubuntu

Comment: Menus issue is solved. But, 4k videos on Chrome fails a lot, dropping so many frames. In other words, the issue is not solved completely.

Comment: @Juan Ignacio Barisich are you on intel graphics or you have a  dedicated GPU?

Comment: @Arko intel graphics 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8, Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

Comment: @Juan Ignacio Barisich I am using the 10th Gen i7 (mobile processor), but I am not facing any problem playing 4k youtube videos. I thought you had a dedicated GPU.

Comment: @Arko no dedicated GPU: Lenovo E15 https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-e-series/E15/p/22TPE15E5N1 Do you have "Fractional scaling" enabled in some of your displays?