# Intel AX200 Wifi not working after update to Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

EDIT: It turned out to be a hardware issue. Replaced my wireless network card and now everything appears to be working fine.

==========================================================================

I have recently updated to Kubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.4) from Kubuntu 19.10 and now my wifi is not working. It seems to work very occasionally but for all intents and purposes, it does not work.

The first thing I noticed, by running `dmesg |grep iwlwifi` was that it appeared to be attempting to load `iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode` followed by `iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode` both of which do not exist on my system and then finally it would load `iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode`.

However, looking at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html would seem to suggest that the correct driver for my device is `iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode`. Therefore, I downloaded this from the git tree and forced my kernel to load it by overwriting `iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode` in `/lib/firmware`.

I thought this would fix the problem, but it has not and I am not sure what to do at this point. Here is the current output of `dmesg |grep iwlwifi`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
jasonb@jason-pc:~$ dmesg |grep iwlwifi
[    3.040001] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.063694] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.063696] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.063885] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.177b3e46.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.112782] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.125898] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.126315] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.283955] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 50:eb:71:da:33:6a
[    3.301432] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.360449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.518769] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    4.530986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[   12.240895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   13.704339] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   14.728587] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   19.720571] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   20.776456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   23.720531] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   24.776483] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   27.464338] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   28.744363] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   29.800544] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   39.024188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   39.688581] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   40.776720] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   52.716839] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   53.800487] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   54.760647] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   65.612484] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   66.728634] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   67.688562] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   79.679563] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   80.680600] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   81.800606] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   91.590532] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   92.808675] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[   93.800381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
```

Also on shutdown, these messages briefly flash across the black screen:

```
[   4.448530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[   4.536318] Bluetooth hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR-

```
sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

credit where credit is due:
[Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow?newreg=89f454f5c3714071a14949ed391721f9)

I ran across the (seemingly) same issue. I am on a Dell XPS 7390 Developer edition with an Intel AX200 wifi card; came with Ubuntu 18.04, and I upgraded to 20.04 with kernel version 5.4 then I started having these same issues - my wifi kept cutting out so it appeared slow even though speed tests would suggest otherwise.

I ran the commands you had above and were getting the same errors - I upgraded my firmware from the intel website (that you have linked above) just in case. I also tried to adjust TLP as suggested by one of the answers in what I linked. I did a reboot between every thing I tried and removing the package is the one that did it for me. If you have that package it might be the culprit. Best of luck.

Comment: This worked for me on my XPS 15 ubuntu 18.04 with Killer AX200 originally installed (with their `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`)