# Is my network connection just extremely slow or is ubuntu not optimised for games?

Tags: networking, nvidia, games, steam

So I recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04 just a week ago for gaming and it's alright except this small issue I have with my network. When I play singleplayer games I get a decent framerate and NO lag, but when I play games like CSGO and DotA 2 I get 120FPS, but there is lag that looks like low FPS (it's not). I used to play the same games on the same network using Windows and it worked just fine. Is there a configuration that I can do to prioritize network traffic for games or something like that?
Thanks.

Comment: Is QoS enabled in your router? Do you have DSL?

Comment: I did the top 2 fixes and the problem is no more. https://askubuntu.com/a/1240386/1103966

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no specific setting for that.

First of all, make sure you are using a wired connection and not wireless.

Try doing a [speed test](https://www.speedtest.net/) to see what your network connection is actually capable of. Be sure to repeat it several times at different times of the day.

Use a system monitor such as gkrellm or conky to verify that your network is not saturated by anything else while you're trying to play.

If your network connection is fine, then it is almost certainly just a matter of connection to the server you happen to play on. A server that was fine one day may be laggy the next. Even if it appears to be due to the OS, it usually is not.

Comment: If speed tests do show that network is slow on Ubuntu compared to Windows(if still have) come back with new question.  I am not good enough but do know there are some network settings that might need adjustment(usually don't).

Comment: So apparently there is a known bug and a fix too. here it is: https://askubuntu.com/a/1240386/1103966

Comment: So it was linked to your WiFi power management settings, right?