# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi really slow

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 on my [ASUS ROG GL553VD](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/742731/asus-rog-strix-gl553vd-dm203t/specificaties/) and since the upgrade, my wifi is extremely slow. I'm running dual boot with Windows 10 and the difference in internet speed on both operating systems is 38.45Mbps (down) on Windows and 0.55Mbps on Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm posting this question because I've searched and tried a lot of options on other forums, but none of them have solved my problem.

[This forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow) had the most options, but none of them had any effect. The backport-iwlwifi-dkms package wasn't even installed on my laptop, turning off power management didn't fix my problem, I tried upgrading to kernel 5.7 as well as downgrading to 5.3, the line in /etc/gai.conf didn't fix my problem, and in Additional Drivers, my Network Adapter didn't have an option to choose drivers.

Does anyone have any other suggestions I could try?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's your MTU? `io link` will show it. MTU for WiFi should be 1492 not 1500.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using the ifconfig command I found out that indeed, my MTU is 1500. However, I've got three interfaces: "enp3s0", "lo" and "wlp2s0". The first and last have MTU 1500 and lo has 65536.

Changing the two from 1500 to 1492 didn't solve my problem.

Do you have another idea? Or something I should do differently? Thanks