# Zoom meeting cannot connect to zoom server, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, zoom-meeting

I have been using Zoom for many months on Ubuntu 18.04.
Now all of a sudden, it has stopped working.
The zoom app cannot start a meeting.  After a minute or so of trying, it says it cannot connect to the Zoom server with error 104114.

Zoom help just says this is a connection problem.

Anyone else have this?  How to diagnose it?

Thanks

Comment: for an emergency use cable if possible. I have same problem, 9 of 10 time fails with wifi

Comment: take a look to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to run it as :
`$ sudo zoom`

Comment: I've had bad experiences running user-level programs with root right for a quick fix. Often files get written in the home-folder with root-rights and thus can cause further trouble. :-/