# WiFi AX200 is not connecting automatically on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: networking, iwlwifi, 20.10

I upgraded my Wireless Card from Intel Wireless 9560 to AX200.
I have Dual Boot Windows OS & Ubuntu 20.10 on my HP Omen.

I updated my wireless driver on my Windows 10 environment.
Everything working perfectly.Every time I boot into my Ubuntu 20.10,
I have to connect to my hidden Wifi every time.

I tried to see if Ubuntu recognizing the AX200 drive.
This is what I found:

```
    krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlw
[sudo] password for krillavilla: 
[    3.259537] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.269345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.270894] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.270911] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    3.270915] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.270917] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.271217] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.271333] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.358293] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.561857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: e0:d4:e8:53:eb:b1
[    3.577475] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ lspci -nn | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

**UPDATE**
I went to the Intel website to load the driver using the instruction
provided on this link [Intel Linux Wireless Driverl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

I still get kicked off my Wifi randomly

***UPDATE***
It's been 4 hours and I did not get kick off my wifi yet.
I did some research and found this article [Kernel Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)
which I already have an updated version of the kernel.

```
krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ uname -r
5.8.0-28-generic
```

Also, people had reported disabling Fast Boot and secure on Windows 10 OS
[Intel Fast Boot](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Unstable-AX200-connection-in-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/1205573#M30527). I already disable Fast boot startup and my secure BIOS is disabled since I have Windows OS dual boot.

Now, my issue is my throughput on my Windows 10 OS speed test is over 120mbps download speed. On my Ubuntu 20.10, I get a 55mbps download speed.
All the other devices connected to my TP-Link AX6000 getting over 200+mpbs download speed. my laptop is the only device that getting less than 200mbps.

Why is that?

***UPDATE***

I restart my computer and Ubuntu 20.10 didn't connect to my Wifi automatically. I have to go to Network Manager and connect it manually.

***UPDATE***

Its been several hours and I didn't get kicked off my wifi but I still
have to connect to it manually after restart or reboot.

I have 4 questions I need help with:

1. Can someone help me resolve this error message:

   ```
    [3.484752] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [3.498326] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
   ```
2. Can someone help me figure out why Ubuntu won't connect to my Wifi
   Automatically after reboot/restart?
3. Can anyone explain to me why my Windows 10 OS has way faster Link speed/throughput than my Ubuntu 20.10? Is there a fix for this issue?

4.Is there a way to install WPA 3 and 802.11ax on my Ubuntu laptop?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I had this issue today when somebody installed Ubuntu 20.10 instead of 20.04 after internet searches and trying lots of things I resolved the problem.

I downloaded the20.04 latest Linux firmware linux-firmware_1.187.4_all.deb

then I uninstalled the 20.10 version using

dpkg -r --force-depends linux-firmware

then installed the old package

dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.187.4_all.deb

Rebooted and everything worked fine...