# Slow internet speed after installing ubuntu 20.04 in chrome

Tags: networking, 20.04, google-chrome, internet

I am a new user to Ubuntu . Previously I used windows 10 . On switching to Ubuntu 20.04 my internet speed get very slow . Even I have checked my internet connection there is not any ping loss . Sometime searching "google.com" in search bar in Chrome it says can't reach to server (such king of error) .

I changed my device DNS server to google DNS - then also no solution , I read an article on askUbuntu which says it's due to Google Chrome DNS , I changed it - then also no solution .
I am very anxious of the problem.
Anyone who has any solution ? It will be really a great help.

Thanking You

Yours Truly

Rishabh Raghwendra

Answer (score 0):

Is your internet speed only slow when using Chrome or also when using Firefox?
If it's also slow when using Firefox, you can maybe check out this post: [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

If it's only in Chrome, maybe you can try to reinstall it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same problem with Firefox too. Your solution didn't work 