# Wifi issues Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless

My laptop wifi sometimes connects to wifi sometimes it doesn't. Wifi works on all my other devices and even on a windows laptop.

input

```bsh
lspci -knn |grep -i net -A2
```

output

```bsh
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I217-LM [1028:0684]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4460]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwif
```

input

```bsh
uname -a
```

output

```bsh
Linux midhun-Precision-M2800 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tried things described in [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

no luck.

Comment: Welcome, please add the output of `lspci -knn |grep -i net -A2` and `uname -a`.

Comment: @GAD3R thanks, updated the results!

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.

Comment: @Pilot6 its ubuntu system. Probably i didn't get what you meant.