# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Download Speed very slow, Upload speed fairly good

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel, internet

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 on my Dell machine Inspiron 3542. Previously on windows OS, the internet through wifi was very good.After I installed ubuntu, I found that download speed is very less, however, the upload speed is relatively good. [image: Internet Speed]
.

The kernel version installed in my machine is 5.8.0-53-generic.[image: System details] [image: Network cards]

I tried various solutions available and found that there does not exist a single solution. The solution I tried from the following link:

- [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)
- [https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/#:~:text=The%20slow%20WiFi%20in%20Ubuntu,these%20Linux%20distributions%20as%20well.&text=Save%20it%2C%20close%20it%2C%20restart,wireless%20connection%20problem%20for%20you](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=The%20slow%20WiFi%20in%20Ubuntu,these%20Linux%20distributions%20as%20well.&text=Save%20it%2C%20close%20it%2C%20restart,wireless%20connection%20problem%20for%20you).

I tried following.

1. Changed the power value from 2 to 3: No significant improvement. Download speed still pretty low < 4 megabits per second
2. Enabling software-based encryption.
3. Tried to remove: "sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms": I got an error saying "Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed"
4. Disable8802.11n

Nothing has worked for me. I think the problem is coming through the kernel. Has anyone faced the same problem. Requesting help.

Comment: How much memory do you have?  How big are the downloads?  What model disk, does it have SMR (Shingled Magnetic Recording), which is know to be a bottleneck.  Search this site for "slow copy" for some suggestions (your network download may be hitting the same sort of write fills the buffers and system slows to a crawl.