# Very slow wired internet connection after motherboard upgrade

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, ethernet

I've upgraded my motherboard from an "MSI B450 Tomahawk Max" to an "MSI Mag X570S Torpedo Max". I did not reinstall Ubuntu and initially, on the first boot, everything seemed to be working fine.

From the second restart onwards, my wired internet has slowed to a crawl. It seems there is a long delay when initially trying to create connections, but once the connection has been made, the speed is reasonable.

For example, I am able to download packages using apt-get and using tools like wget and curl work reasonably well. However, I can't install snaps though, they always fail with "unexpected HTTP status code 408 via POST to 'https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh". Both Firefox and Chrome take a very long time to load everything. We are talking multiple minutes with several refreshes just to bring up the google home page. I can see in the network panel that many resources are just failing to load because it is taking so long to connect and by refreshing, I am serving up the successful ones from a local cache allowing more connections to succeed next time. Once they do connect, they download quite fast.

I have tried running speedtest-cli and regularly get "Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration ERROR: The read operation timed out". When it does manage to do so, the download speeds measured vary wildly and are sometimes terrible and sometimes okay. I have a ~100MB connection and the fastest I've measured is 103.81MB but it will often measure 80, 60 and even as low as 2MB, quite often.

I have tried the following with no change in behavior:

- Running an Ubuntu live USB.
- Downgrading from r8169 to r8168.
- Switching to a different Ethernet port (the motherboard has 2: 1GB and 2.5GB)
- Setting network.dns.disableIPv6 to true in Firefox.
- Switching ethernet cables
- Switching back to the original motherboard

**Update** Fixed it. It was my router. See my answer.

Comment: @Nmath thanks for the tip. I felt that booting from a live USB should have eliminated that possibility but just to check, I switched back to the original motherboard and found that the issue remains.

Comment: @Nmath no problem, I completely understand. I will go ahead and delete. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nmath unfortunately, I cannot delete and when I try, I get an error saying that this is because the question has answers. I've voted to close instead.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a case of unfortunate timing and the motherboard upgrade was completely irrelevant.

I tried the same Ethernet cable with another computer and found the exact same networking issue. All other devices in my house were working (both wired and wireless) so I didn't suspect my router but restarting my router fixed the issue.

Sigh... what a waste of time!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Answer posted here helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1396350/1700811

What's is saying you need to update your realtek driver to dkms one by wrtiting into console:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
sudo echo "blacklist r8169"  > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf
reboot
```

I need to notice that command:

```
sudo echo "blacklist r8169"  > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf
```

casted "access denied" error, but it still repaired my ethernet speed.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm afraid I have already seen that post, and tried it, with no change in behavior. Also worth noting that I've been on r8169 for months without this issue occurring. However, the same issue is observed with r8168 also.