# No wifi connection after upgrade to kernel 5.17.8 ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, upgrade, kernel, 22.04

My new ubuntu 22.04 LTS has wifi problem. My wifi disconnect frequently. I found some [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404358/1155600) to upgrade kernel from 5.15 to 5.17. Then I upgrade to 5.17 kernel using this command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.5-051705_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-modules-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

And now no wifi visible on top bar and setting. I use HP 1000.

**Network hardware info**

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A7
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Marilyn HB125 1x1 802.11bgn
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485/HB125 802.11bgn 1×1 Wi-Fi Adapter [103c:1838]
    Kernel modules: ath9k
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:21e9]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network  
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 05
       serial: 8c:dc:d4:d6:42:c9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.17.8-051708-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f1104000-f1104fff memory:f1100000-f1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1200000-f127ffff memory:f1280000-f128ffff
```

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep ath
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.17.8-051708-generic (kernel@kathleen) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #202205151940 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 15 20:04:23 UTC 2022
[    5.350372] ath: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz
[    5.350380] ath: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -22)
[    5.350394] ath: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
[    5.350396] ath: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
[    5.350407] ath: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
[    5.350408] ath: Unknown symbol freq_reg_info (err -22)
```

**My Temporary solution**

Now, I have downgraded my ubuntu kernel to `5.13.19-051319-generic` to solve my wifi problem. This is not the best solution, but I can work without interruption for a while until a new update on the kernel fixed my wifi problem.

Comment: There is no information to answer. We don't know what is the hardware.

Comment: @Pilot6, I've added network info.

Comment: Please run the command with `-A3` anther line is needed. Probably something is wrong with the specific kernel. You can always boot with a previous one and remove this one.

Comment: @Pilot6 new line added.

Comment: It looks good. Another line would be good to see if the module is in use. Also add `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: But generally this device is well supported and changing to an unsupported kernel was not a good idea. Most likely antenna has a bad contact, etc.

Comment: I can use my wifi if I change it back to 5.15. But wifi connection is disconnected frequently.

Comment: `ath9k` doesn't load due to some bug in the kernel. The easiest solution is to use Ubuntu 20.04 for a while, I guess. Maybe it is related with some new format of regulatory db...

Comment: Now, I use 5.13 kernel on my ubuntu 22 and my wifi issue is gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)