# Internet access speed drops suddenly

Tags: networking, internet

I have been using Ubuntu for six years. Since 20.04 LTS, the internet access (wifi) drops suddenly and randomly from 20Mb/s for download to 1Mb/s or even below! Sometimes it works flawlessly, sometimes I need to reboot twice a day. Unfortunately, the problem persists in Ubuntu 22.04 too.

I tried out most of the tricks recommended here but with no avail:  https://blog.rottenwifi.com/ubuntu-slow-internet/

According to some, the standard 5.15 kernel in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is responsible for bad wifi behaviour. One guy recommends downgrading to 5.13 the other one prefers upgrading to 5.17: [wifi issues in ubuntu 22.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403954/wifi-issues-in-ubuntu-22-04lts)

What to do???

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just want to add that the internet access on a different laptop running under MS Windows works perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps you shoult tell about your kind of internet connection and your network konnection, pe. use DSL or UMTS and use Rthernet or WiFi and so on.

Comment: I am using Wifi. I apologize myself for being an utter layman in IT - I just like Linux.

Comment: Tell about your wifi connection. Name of router, name of your wifi card.

Comment: also, it'd be helpful to know if you are using any VPN service

Comment: alfx my Opera browser uses its built-in VPN feature.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of your wifi router and set to follow values if possible:

- Place your router on a good place. See follow: https://blog.gl-inet.com/my-wifi-is-slow-where-to-place-my-router/
- Set the right country. Depend on law, different country`s have different count and power of wifi channels. So it shouldn't be set different on your router and your pc.
- Set your channel selection on you router to auto channel.
- If possible, use MiMo supporting devices (thats supportted by a part of wifi5 and all WiFi6 devices). This one have a much better handling in environments with a high count of wifi devices.
- Enable DFS support on your router, if possible. That protect you a little bit about wifi issues around airports, which are related on weather radar.
- Often you find a menue item on your router like "Do you like to support "b, g, n, ac, ax", if you dont need and if possible, disable "WiFi b and g" on your router.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input Alfred 37! However, do you really believe it may be a router-issue? When having checked with my wife yesterday after the download speed on my laptop had dropped again from 24Mb/s to 0.5Mb/s, the speedtest on her MS Windows-powered computer gave 13Mb/s for download. Her laptop is using the same router as mine. Is it not rather a Ubuntu-Linux flaw?  Just my two cents...

Comment: @AndrásSzőllős those additional bits of information would be better placed as an edit in your original question.