# Weak Wi-Fi signal on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, ASUS laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, asus, iwlwifi

I am new to Linux. Immediately encountered the problem of very weak wifi signal, that i haven't on windows.
I've already seen the solutions for HP laptops, and none of them worked for me. Tried to change kernel as well (I heard that 5.15 version is kinda buggy in this context), but still nothing.
I got following output for `lshw -C network` command:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:c6:81:dc:69:82
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.17.13-051713-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.6.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a441c000-a441ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: d4:5d:64:64:3c:48
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.17.13-051713-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

And for  `lspci` it is

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 10)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

I thought that updating WiFi driver would help, but saddly there's no version I can update for.

I would be incredibly grateful if someone could help

**UPD 1.**
Result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` is following. Where Androidha is my phone on which I turned on the hotspot and I literally placed my phone on the laptop, and it's still, not even close to "strong signal", the phone itself is connected to one of these other WiFi. Two other routers are in adjacent room.

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID       MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       BA:C0:86:C4:F2:55  Androidha  Infra  1     117 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA3      
        AC:22:05:7B:A6:B3  ANM19      Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        38:A6:59:D6:DC:67  T-U3E4cU   Infra  36    540 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
```

Comment: I wish I had the same WiFi card so I could help there, but +1 to your question to hopefully help you on your way that someone here might have figured this out as I have seen others asking.  However, that being said, I did notice that you are using the `r8169` driver on the `RTL 8168` card.  That driver is very flaky on the 8168 card and seems to be the default one chosen for that card.  You can fix it by installing the `r8168` driver.  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.
But thank you for your responsiveness

Comment: My comment above won't fix the WiFi, but it will help your ethernet connection if you use it.

Comment: How weak is it? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact all the MAC addesses with XXXX. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: From your question "(I heard that 5.15 version is kinda buggy in this context)" Do you have a link I  can go to to read this for myself?

Comment: For example this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403954/wifi-issues-in-ubuntu-22-04lts . But it's not the only thread discussing this problem, all other are on different pages.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?  If you read through that link that you posted in your comment they are stating that the WiFi signal seems to be fixed in Kernel version `5.15.0-33` and possibly newer.

Comment: Well not for me. I tried 5.17, 6.05 and 5.13 kernels version. Nothing had an effect.