# My ubuntu 20.04 wifi very slow

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless

I just boot a new ubuntu 20.04.3, and when I restart my wifi gets slow, and sometimes it automatically disconnected:

My ubuntu version 20.04.4 when already update

[image: ubuntu version]

What I have tried:

- reboot the computer multiple time
- check if the problem is from hardware, but it is not because of hardware

[image: check if hardware problem]

- I try to change `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` the value from 3 to 2, saved changes and rebooted.follow this : [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

[image: try available solution]

- I try to update my ubuntu to version 20.04.4
- I also try to boot ubuntu 20.04 again on my computer

But all the above solutions no one work for me.

Comment: What's your WiFi MTU? `ip link` will show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: @waltinator 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:f5:05:ff:50:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0  I got this output

Comment: is the speed normal if you use the wired connection? what is the signal level and link quality,you can use the terminal program wavemon to see this and what speeds up/down do wavemon show?

Comment: Read my answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 it explains why WiFi is "slow" (packet fragmenting) and what to do. AskUbuntu doesn't want duplicate answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Ubuntu 20.04.

I also changed the wifi.powersave from 3 to 2, but it didn't work.

The solution for me was editing the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and replacing the line:
`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`
with
`hosts:          files dns`.

This change increased the speed from approximately 35 Mbps to 380 Mbps. I got this tip from here https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/.

So far, the wifi connection also looks stable.