Help with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and slow internet connection
TLDR:
Installed ubuntu 24.04 lts and suddenly my internet connection is super slow. (13Mbps compared to 580Mbps for other devices). Any suggestions?
Problem:
I used to have a windows 11, moved to ubuntu. Installed 24.04lts version. Internet seems to be very very slow. Tried couple of other suggestions, such as disabling power management for wifi, update and upgrade the system. These does not seem to do the trick. When i look at the device from the router (Atnt) I see a very low link rate (30mbps) whereas every single other device falls at around 500 mbps. Furthermore, I'm using qualcom network adapter since the one that the dell alienware aurora r7 had, kind of stopped working when i changed the case since the case was too small. So in additional drivers, it shows Broadcom Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Dualband wireless network adapter, I'm not sure if that is the correct one. The one that I am using is - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac.
What steps I took?

Tried to disable the power management

Command to check the network card -  lspci -nnk | grep -i net


07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0858]
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]


Command to check the network status. - iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"cemetery"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: E0:1F:2B:3E:2F:AC   
          Bit Rate=13.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=24 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:40   Missed beacon:0


Tried a couple of suggestions from here- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow

However, still no luck. Can anyone please help me. I kind of feel like I'm running in circles.

did you consider these resources? It's FOSS Ubuntu Documentation Super User

I did, but none of those methods worked. I tried both options from the first document, but the latter one made it even slower :/
